# Запятая перед ‘и’ в придаточном, присоединённом союзом ‘зато’

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед И:
Курорт небольшой, зато на пляже песок и торговцы не пристают.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. Это однородные члены (песок, торговцы), соединённые непарным союзом *и*.

Придаточное присоединено к главному при помощи противительного союза "зато", он-то и является общим членом для двух основ:

*зато на пляже песок и* (зато) *торговцы не пристают.*

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Лопатину,

2. Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится:

Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых.

Он подавил вздох и не спеша стал сворачивать папироску, но почему-то дрогнули руки, и он рассыпал на колени табак.

Гроза прошла, и тучи рассеялись, но духота ещё сохранялась.

У вас тогда:

Курорт небольшой, зато (но) на пляже песок, и торговцы не пристают.

так как ЗАТО, как и НО, - противительный союз.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)Курорт небольшой, зато (2) на пляже песок и (3)торговцы не пристают.**

Сложное предложение с тремя предикативными основами. Союз ЗАТО относится к предложениям (2) и (3), соединенными одиночным союзом И, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Союз ***ЗАТО*** иногда называют противительным, однако он не равен союзам НО (А) и имеет **значение возместительного сопоставления.**

**ЗАТО**, союз. 1. **Употр. при возместительном сопоставлении; но в то же время, однако.** Дорого, з. добротная вещь. 2. Употр. при пояснении или для выражения следствия; **поэтому, вследствие этого**. Не слушалась, з. теперь жалеет об этом. Подруга очень щепетильна, з. ей многие доверяют. <Но зато; а зато, союз. =Зато (1 зн.). Устали, но зато поработали на славу.

Comment: А есть ли какое-то правило, приравнивающее (в отношении пунктуации) _союз_ к общему для двух предложений _члену предложения_?

Comment: В правилах упоминаются вводные слова и частицы в качестве общего элемента. У Розенталя есть упоминание о том, что  "противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом И простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед И ставится": Из этого можно заключить, что в принципе союз может быть общим элементом.  В нашем случае это и так очевидно: первое предложение сопоставлено с двумя другими с помощью союза ЗАТО.

Comment: А в какой книжке у Розенталя? Я не нашёл этого здесь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm

Comment: Это справочник Розенталя    http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133    (Примечание 2  к п. 2).